# Properly define constraint for a true one to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

We have in our system a one to one relation.

Let's use the typical example of user -> address:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
end
```

In this scenario, the user has an `address_id` field, the address doesn't have any database field that references the user.

When I now go ahead and create a user and an address, everything is fine:

```
user = User.create(address: Address.create)
```

But when I create an additional address with the existing user I will end up with 2 addresses.

```
address.create(user: user)
```

Usually not a big deal, but for reporting purposes stuff can go wrong.

So my question: how do I make sure there is only one user associated with one address and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

To truly enforce it, you can define a unique index on the `users.address_id` column.

In general I'd suggest just not using `Address.create` though: if you use `address.create_user`, Active Record will do a better (though still not perfect, especially in the face of concurrent requests) job of keeping things under control for you.

(Creating a user from an address doesn't make much sense, of course... if you went down that path, I'd consider flipping the relationship to make the Address feel more subordinate to the User. The point is that manipulating it via the `has_one` side will get you more `has_one`-aware behaviour.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue you're running into might have more to do with the controller than with model constraints.

Your `User` model could `accept_nested_attributes_for :address`.

Your new and edit actions could look something like this:

```rb
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_address
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.build_address if @user.address.blank?
end
```

And your user form could have something like:

```rb
<%= fields_for :address do |address_form| %>
  <%= address_form.text_field :street_line_one %>
  <%= address_form.text_field :street_line_two %>
  <%= address_form.text_field :city %>
  <%= address_form.text_field :postal_code %>
  <%= address_form.text_field :region_name %>
<% end %>
```

This should ensure that a new object is created when a new user is created, and should ensure that the existing address is updated when the user with an existing address is updated.

If that's still not working as expected, you'll have to add a bit more detail like what your controller and form look like to know exactly how to solve your issue.